# How to prove this interesting inequality: $\frac{5x+3y+z}{5z+3y+x}+\frac{5y+3z+x}{5x+3z+y}+\frac{5z+3x+y}{5y+3x+z}\ge 3$?

Tags: inequality, polynomials, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

Here is my question:

> Prove that if $x,y,z>0$ then $$\frac{5x+3y+z}{5z+3y+x}+\frac{5y+3z+x}{5x+3z+y}+\frac{5z+3x+y}{5y+3x+z}\ge 3$$

Here is my attempt:

> Let us assume $x>y>z$:
>   \begin{align*}
> 4x+x+z &> 4z+x+z\\
> 5x+z &> x+5z\\
> 5x+3y+z &> x+3y+5z\\
> \frac{5x+3y+z}{x+3y+5z} &> 1
> \end{align*}

The question is given by my high school teacher as a challenge questions in my class.

I want to understand what is the difference between a cyclic inequality and symmetric inequality. Why $\frac{5x+3y+z}{5z+3y+x}+\frac{5y+3z+x}{5x+3z+y}+\frac{5z+3x+y}{5y+3x+z}\ge 3$ is not a symmetric inequality?

Comment: you can assume x>y>z, and try to attack it

Comment: @Vivek how? can you please show me?

Comment: How did you arrive at this equation ? Did you try to multiply with all the denominators ?

Comment: @Peter I tried, but it is not helping.

Comment: Why is this inequality interesting?

Answer (score 2):

It's $$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{5x+3y+z}{x+3y+5z}-1\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x-z}{x+3y+5z}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-z)(y+3z+5x)(z+3x+5y)\geq0$$ or  $$\sum_{cyc}(x-z)(15x^2+5y^2+3z^2+28xy+14xz+16yz)\geq0$$ or $$\sum_{cyc}(15x^3+5x^2z+3x^2y+28x^2y+14x^2z+16xyz-$$
$$-15x^2z-5x^2y-3x^3-28xyz-14x^2y-16x^2z)\geq0$$ or
$$12\sum_{cyc}(x^3+x^2y-x^2z-xyz)\geq0,$$ which is true by Rearrangement and AM-GM.

Also, we can use C-S.

Indeed,
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{5x+3y+z}{x+3y+5z}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(5x+3y+z)^2}{(x+3y+5z)(5x+3y+z)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(5x+3y+z)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x+3y+5z)(5x+3y+z)}\geq3,$$
where the last inequality it's just $$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\geq0.$$
The inequality is named symmetric if it does not depend on all permutations of variables.

For example, the inequality $$a+b+c\geq3$$ is symmetric because for all permutations of $a$, $b$ and $c$ we obtain the same inequality:
$$a+b+c\geq3;$$
$$a+c+b\geq3;$$
$$b+a+c\geq3;$$
$$b+c+a\geq3;$$ 
$$c+a+b\geq3$$ and
$$c+b+a\geq3.$$
Easy to see that they are the same.

The inequality is named cyclic if it does not depend on all cyclic permutations of variables.

For example, the following inequality is cyclic.
$$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\geq3.$$
Cyclic permutations ($a\rightarrow b\rightarrow c\rightarrow a$) give:
$$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\geq3;$$
$$b^2c+c^2a+a^2b\geq3$$ and $$c^2a+a^2b+b^2c\geq3.$$
Easy to see that they are the same.

By the way, the last inequality is not symmetric because we can not say that it does not depend on all permutations of our variables.

For example, take the permutation $(a,b,c)\rightarrow(a,c,b)$.

By this permutation we get from $$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\geq3$$ the following:
$$a^2c+c^2b+b^2a\geq3,$$ which is something another.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg what should be $\sum_{sym}\left(\frac{5x+3y+z}{x+3y+5z}\right)\geq3$ should be written as?

Comment: It's exactly your inequality. I added something in my post. See now.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I got it... Thanks for your answer!!! There is a typing mistake in your answer, I don't have edit privilege so I can't correct it... Instead of $a+b+a\geq3$ it should be $c+b+a\geq3$ and instead of "inequality named cyclic/symmetric" it should be "inequality is named cyclic/symmetric"

Comment: My English is very bad. I fixed. :)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg as you said this inequality is symmetric, so can I use the technique "If both sides of an inequality are symmetric functions then there is no loss of generality in assuming $x>y>z$" ? Then I can add the three different inequalities $\frac{5x+3y+z}{x+3y+5z}> 1$ to get my resulting inequality.

Comment: I think you understood right about assuming $x\geq y\geq z$ in the symmetric inequality. The inequality $\frac{5x+3y+z}{x+3y+5z}>1$ is wrong. You can't add nothing. You need to prove the given  inequality only.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg why is it wrong? Thanks for being patient with me

Comment: Try $x=y\rightarrow0^+$. You can't assume that $x\geq y\geq z$ because the starting inequality is not symmetric. By the way, you can assume that $z=\min\{x,y,z\}$.

Comment: see this https://imgur.com/a/sBAIp here they are adding three different inequalities to prove the required question

Comment: I saw. It's a symmetric inequality. You see the adding of three true inequalities. In your trying you add three  inequalities and not all of them are true because you can not assume that $x\geq y\geq z$.

Comment: you just said that the inequality is symmetric, now you are saying that the starting inequality is not symmetric? "It's exactly your inequality" $\sum_{sym}\left(\frac{5x+3y+z}{x+3y+5z}\right)\geq3$

Comment: ok... I will try to understand

Comment: Sorry, I did not see "sym". I thought that it's "cyc".  If so it's symmetric of course. I said all time about your starting inequality.

Comment: which one is my starting inequality that you were saying about?

Comment: You can not assume that $x>y>z$. Thus, there all is wrong.